# basic buildspec.yml for next js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
        nodejs: 12
    commands:
        - echo Installing dependencies with Yarn...
        - yarn set version berry  # Set Yarn Berry as the Yarn version
        - yarn install  # Use Yarn Berry to install dependencies

 build:
    commands:
        - echo Build started on `date`
        - echo Compiling the Node.js code...
        - yarn build  # Use Yarn Berry to run the build script

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo doing nothing

artifacts:
  files:
    - '**/*'
  discard-paths: yes
```

im trying to deploy very simple next js application using aws services.
to get used to the services like route53, cloudfront, codepipeline etc...

i'm using yarn berry as a package manager in my local next js project.
so i'm trying to use yarn berry in my buildspec too. (if it is even possible and reasonable)

i get an error on my aws codebuild

```
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:04:17 Waiting for agent ping
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:04:48 Waiting for DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:05:10 Phase is DOWNLOAD_SOURCE
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:05:10 CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR=/codebuild/output/src143957957/src
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:05:10 YAML location is /codebuild/output/srcDownload/src/buildspec.yml
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:05:10 Phase complete: DOWNLOAD_SOURCE State: FAILED
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:05:10 Phase context status code: YAML_FILE_ERROR Message: did not find expected key at line 11
agent_1  | [Container] 2023/10/28 03:05:10 Runtime error (*clienterr.PhaseContextError: did not find expected key at line 11)
agent-resources_build_1 exited with code 11
```

what is the problem with the yml file?
and could you give me a sample code for my purpose please?

and let me know if it is reasonable to use yarn berry in code build environment.
thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have incorrect **indentation**. It should be:

```
---
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 12
    commands:
      - echo Installing dependencies with Yarn...
      - yarn set version berry
      - yarn install
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Compiling the Node.js code...
      - yarn build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo doing nothing
artifacts:
  files:
    - "**/*"
  discard-paths: yes
```